# R: taking the average of data by indicators when there are multiple indicators

Tags: r, average, subset, plyr

I have a data frame that has a `rating` and 4 genre indicators `Genre.1`, `Genre.2`, `Genre.3`, `Genre.4`. Each gene indicator has a range from 0-16 that corresponds to which genre was most prevalent.

I want to take the average `rating` for each genre. Ie the average `rating` for whenever there is a 1 in `Genre.1:4`, then taking the average rating for whenever there is a 2 in `G1:4`.

Finally I wish to take the average of the averages. Ie. if `Genre.1` is 1 and `Genre.2` is 2, then it would take the average of `Genre.1` and the average of `Genre.2`

My code works up until I try to take the average of the average. Anyone have any advice on a cleaner way to do this? Anyone have any advice on taking the average of average better?

I want to end up with `ID` and the average rating by the genres it has listed.

```
pred <- data.frame(1:6,
               c(1,2,3,1,2,5),
               c(4,5,4,3,4,5),
               c(1,1,1,1,2,3),
               c(1,2,1,2,1,3),
               c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
               c(2,3,4,3,2,5))
names(pred) <- 
  c("ID", "User.ID", "Rating", "Genre.1", "Genre.2", "Genre.3", "Genre.4")

temp <- subset(pred, Genre.1 == 1 | Genre.2 == 1 | Genre.3 == 1 | Genre.4 == 1)

temp1 <- ddply(temp, c("Genre.1", "User.ID"), summarise, avg = mean(Rating))

temp <- subset(pred, Genre.1 == 2 | Genre.2 == 2 | Genre.3 == 2 | Genre.4 == 2)

temp2 <- ddply(temp, c("Genre.1", "User.ID"), summarise, avg = mean(Rating))

temp <- subset(pred, Genre.1 == 3 | Genre.2 == 3 | Genre.3 == 3 | Genre.4 == 3)

temp3 <- ddply(temp, c("Genre.1", "User.ID"), summarise, avg = mean(Rating))

temp4 <- rbind(temp1, temp2, temp3)

test <- rbind(temp1, temp2, temp3, temp4)
names(test) <- c("Genre", "User.ID", "Rating")

temp <- join(test, pred, by = "User.ID", type = "full")

# this gives the format I want but does not discern if the genre is present 
# for the average.
test <- ddply(temp, "ID", summarise, avg = mean(Rating))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your data from long to wide format first. You can subset the values from there. The example below finds the average for everything.

```
library(reshape2)
library(plyr)

pred2 <- melt(pred, id=c("ID", "User.ID", "Rating"))
means <- ddply(pred2, .(variable), summarize, mean.values = mean(value))
mean(means$mean.values) #mean of means
```

EDIT:

Return a list of the average for all genre values:

```
lapply(1:4, function(x) ddply(pred2[pred2$value == x, ], .(variable), summarize, mean = mean(value)))
```